# Como validar que un objeto JSON con un array dentro no este vacio

Tags: javascript, json, validación

Buenas tardes compañeros, estuve rato pensando en como plantear mi problema y espero ser especifico.
Tengo una funcion que crea un objeto JSON y dentro de el un array.

```js
// Se crea un array vacio para almacenar los datos 
var dataProfile = [];
// Funcion que recibe como parametros los valores de los inputs y los guarda en un objeto JSON
function addData(name, lastname, age, phone, mail) {
    var profile = {
        dName: name,
        dApellido: lastname,
        dAge: age,
        dPhone: phone,
        dMail: mail
    };
    dataProfile.push(profile);
    storage(dataProfile);
}
```

Luego tengo estas tres funciones que lo que hacen es traer del localStorage los datos que se guardaron de los inputs del formulario.

```js
//Funcion que toma el valor de los inputs y se los pasa a la function addData para almacenarlos.
function saveProfile() {
    var dataName = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    var dataApellido = document.querySelector('#apellido').value;
    var dataAge = document.querySelector('#age').value;
    var dataPhone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
    var dataMail = document.querySelector('#mail').value;
    addData(dataName, dataApellido, dataAge, dataPhone, dataMail);

}
function storage(list) {
    localStorage.setItem("profileList", JSON.stringify(list));
}

    function validate() {
        var parseLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profileList"));
        if (localStorage.length !== 0 ) {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < parseLocal.length; i++) {
                data = parseLocal[i];
                var dataName = document.querySelector('#name').value = parseLocal[i].dName
                var dataApellido = document.querySelector('#apellido').value = parseLocal[i].dApellido;
                var dataAge = document.querySelector('#age').value = parseLocal[i].dAge;
                var dataPhone = document.querySelector('#phone').value = parseLocal[i].dPhone;
                var dataMail = document.querySelector('#mail').value = parseLocal[i].dMail;
        
        
            }
            }
    }
```

El problema es que si los inputs estan vacios me guarda los datos igual, yo lo que quiero es que si algun campo esta vacio  (campo = "") agregarle un classList. He probado un monton de cosas pero no pude lograrlo, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si los inputs están vacíos, basta que hagas la comprobación en la función `saveProfile()`, antes de pasárselos como parámetro a la función `addData()`.

```js
document.querySelector('#validar').onclick = function(){
  //Capturamos valor name
  var name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  //Comprobamos si está vació
  if (name === ''){
    //Añadimos el classList al elemento
    document.querySelector('#name').classList.add("error");
  }
};
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="" />
<button id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me dijiste pero no me funciono,  ahora cuando le doy al boton guardar no hace nada, no sale el error con el campo vacio y tampoco me genera la key del localStorage cuando relleno los campos, no se que pueda ser

Comment: Bueno pude solucionar, lo que hice fue, dentro de la funcion saveData() puse condicionales if y else con las condiciones que queria que cumpliera, no fue la mejor solucion por que me quedo el codigo largo y desprolijo pero funciona